# Dynamics CRM Plugin: Calling WebClient with certificate in sandbox mode

Tags: c#, plugins, certificate, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to create a CRM workflow plugin that calls an external webservice using a clientcertificate. I can load the certificate into memory (basically hardcoding it) and assign it to a WebClient, but since it's running in sandboxed-mode, I'm not allowed to actually perform the call using the certficate in a WebClient (a SecurityPermission exception is thrown).

I understand why I wouldn't be able to load a certificate in sandboxed mode from outside the sandbox, but what is the reason I am not allowed to call the webservice using this certificate if I already have it? Should this theoretically be possible or will I have to find other means (such as a proxy or running outside the sandbox)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven’t already, disable sandbox mode - to confirm sandbox mode is the culprit.

If that is the case, there isn't much you can do (apart from as you suggested using an alternative means; proxy, outside of sandbox).

Sandbox mode exists so that multiple CRM organisations can run within a single environment (i.e. CRM Online) without interfering with each other, e.g. accessing another users database.

The MSDN describes Sandbox mode but unfortunately it doesn’t exhaustively what is restricted.

**[Plug-in isolation, trusts, and statistics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx)**

> In this isolated environment, also known as a sandbox, a plug-in or
>   custom activity can make use of the full power of the Microsoft
>   Dynamics 365 SDK to access the organization web service. **Access to the
>   file system, system event log, certain network protocols, registry,
>   and more is prevented in the sandbox.**
>
> ...
>
> **Web Access**
>
> Sandboxed plug-ins and custom workflow activities can access the
>   network through the HTTP and HTTPS protocols. This capability provides
>   support for accessing popular web resources like social sites, news
>   feeds, web services, and more. The following web access restrictions
>   apply to this sandbox capability.
>
> - Only the HTTP and HTTPS protocols are allowed.
> - Access to localhost (loopback) is not permitted.
> - IP addresses cannot be used. You must use a named web address that    requires DNS name resolution.
> - **Anonymous authentication is supported and recommended.** There is no provision for prompting the logged on user for credentials or
>     savingthose credentials.